# Does webpack build multiple entry point files in parallel?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build

In my webpack config I have several entry points. I am trying to figure out if webpack builds them all in parallel or not? The build process takes a little longer and am trying to improve the webpack build time.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from webpack version 4, it supports parallel processing for multiple entry points by default.

But,If there are shared dependencies between entry points, webpack may need to build those dependencies before processing the individual entry points. In such cases, parallel build process can be limited to some extent.

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to this information in their documentation. If you have one, could you please link it here?

Comment: 1) https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#multi-page-application 2) https://medium.com/box-tech-blog/how-we-improved-webpack-build-performance-by-95-864a3a919d69 3) https://github.com/martin-jung-hs/webpack-101 4) https://medium.com/hootsuite-engineering/webpack-101-an-introduction-to-webpack-3f59d21edeba

Comment: All the links you shared discuss multiple entry points, but couldn't find a single reference to the answer I am looking for - Does webpack build multiple entry point files in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a webpack config for each entry point and use [webpack-parallel](https://github.com/trivago/parallel-webpack) or [webpack-multithread](https://github.com/Patrokl42/webpack-multithread) to build it in parallel.